# Unit-Test System.IO.Pipelines using MemoryStream

Tags: c#, xunit

I am trying to test my basic System.IO.Pipelines setup where the memory from the writer will be filled from a TcpClient's stream (`ReadAsync`-method) similar to [this](https://github.com/vbondaryuk/TcpPipelinesSample/blob/master/Client/Program.cs) code.

```
Memory<byte> memory = writer.GetMemory(minimumBufferSize);
int read = await stream.ReadAsync(memory);
```

The `NetworkStream` from the `TcpClient` will prevent the continuation if it's waiting for data / if there is no data to read. I am using interfaces of all network-related parts (Stream, TcpClient, ...) to mock them within unit-tests. Within my tests I use MemoryStreams within my mocks

```
streamMock
.Setup(m => m.ReadAsync(It.IsAny<Memory<byte>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
.Returns((Memory<byte> memory, CancellationToken token) =>
{
     return memStream.ReadAsync(memory, cancelToken);
}
```

The problem is, that the used MemoryStream will always continue instantly with 0 bytes read, as `ReadAsync` is only a asynchronous wrapper around `Read`. Is it possible to get a similar `NetworkStream`-behaviour described above within my unit-tests?

Comment: What is the behavior you want to simulate? If you want to make the MemoryStream wait when it has no bytes (therefore to wait until you feed it some bytes), a possible solution can be to use a wrapper around MemoryStream and to override Read or ReadAsync methods and to check and sleep until the buffer has some bytes. The call would still be blocking though. Or you can wait for an async method inside AsyncRead which fills your memory stream

Comment: That is exactly what I've been / I've was looking for. "Or you can wait for an async method inside AsyncRead which fills your memory stream" - I didn't thought of ManualResetEvent in the first place, but it was the first thing I've thought of reading your comment - It's working now. If you provide something as solution i can check it as solved (rather than the comment)

Comment: The comment is fine :) Your problem being solved is what matters.

Comment: There's nothing built-in for this, no. You'd need to make your own `Stream`-derived class.

Comment: If anyone has the same requirements to implement such a `Stream`-derived class: I can highly recommend taking a look at @StephenCleary's AsyncEx-library - it was really helpful